# How do I make a player not "spaz" out when strafing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So in unity, I have been working on making this third person controller script work, and so far it works how I want it to work, just that now I'm stuck on how to make him move forward and left at the same time (or other direction like that) Cause right now he just starts bugging out.

Movement code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
public class Character_Controler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public float speed = 1f;
    // the world-relative desired move direction, calculated from the camForward and user input.
    private bool canJump = false;
    Vector3 movement;
    Rigidbody playerRbody;

        void Awake()
        {
            playerRbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        playerRbody.AddForce(Physics.gravity * playerRbody.mass);
       // float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
       // float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        var jump = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space);
        if (!canJump && playerRbody.velocity.y == 0)
        {
            canJump = true;

        }
        if (jump && canJump == true)
        {
            playerRbody.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 6f, 0), ForceMode.Impulse);
            canJump = false;
        }
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
         {
             moveForward(speed);
         }
         else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
         {
             moveBack(speed);
         }

         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
         {
             moveLeft(speed);
         }
         else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
         {
             moveRight(speed);
         }
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, transform.localEulerAngles.y, transform.localEulerAngles.z);
        //transform.forward = Camera.main.transform.forward;

    }

    }
    private void moveForward(float speed)
    {
        transform.forward = Camera.main.transform.forward;
        // Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transf);
        // playerRbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);
        transform.localPosition += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    private void moveBack(float speed)
    {
        transform.forward = -Camera.main.transform.forward;
        transform.localPosition += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    }

    private void moveRight(float speed)
    {
        transform.forward = Camera.main.transform.right;
        transform.localPosition += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    private void moveLeft(float speed)
    {
        transform.forward = -Camera.main.transform.right;
        transform.localPosition += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: If your player has a rigidbody, why are you directly modifying the transform's position? Also you should just do all the movement in one function, not 4.

Comment: @XanderLuciano This was the only way I got the player to work as I wanted, I will explain in detail in a bit, have to go afk for abit.

Answer (score 0):

Do not handle the transform position like that.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html

And Vector3.Up * 6f is the same as new Vector3(0, 6, 0);
If you want your player to move up, but he is rotated differently, he wont move up in relation to his rotation by using a new Vector3(), use its transform to find out where up is pointing.

I would also recommend not moving the player based off camera right/up/left/etc.